# I am not able to log in to my system

Tags: ubuntu, login, google-authenticator

I was using 2-factor authentication (google-authenticator with my password) for logging into my system. I accidentally deleted ".google-authenticator file". Now the tab for "verification code" has gone and the only tab for the password appears. When I put my password, it is giving "invalid username or password" error. Can anyone help me with this? I will be very thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: As usual in such cases, the answer is "restore from backups". Let this be a lesson.

Comment: That will be the last resort anyway. I was looking for something else. Thanks.